# SubArray Sum of Fibonacci Number

Tags: algorithm, math, fibonacci

I have an array A of `N` numbers. I have to find the sum of Fibonacci numbers of the sum of all its subarrays.
For example:

```
A = {1,1}
F[Sum A[1,1]] = F[1] = 1
F[Sum A[1,2]] = F[2] = 1
F[Sum A[2,2]] = F[1] = 1
Ans = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
```

The question is similar to [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/sears-dots-arrows/challenges/modified-fibonacci-1) one, but I need to compute the sum for a standard Fibonacci sequence. 
Here is the [source code](http://ideone.com/VIbx9J).
What property is used here ?
Can any one explain math behind this? How to avoid an `O(N^2)` solution? How to modify the source code for standard Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Solving Fibonacci using dynamic programming is `O(n)`, while solving it using recursion is `O(2^n)`.  Where did you see an `O(n^2)` solution anywhere?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. It looks like you are finding the sums of each subarray, and for each sum S finding the Sth fibonacci number, and adding the resulting fibonacci numbers. So each subarray is assigned a fibonacci number, and the results are added. Is this correct? An example that didn't contain so many ones might help.

Comment: @RoryDaulton i have updated it

Comment: @DavidBowling it's correct so total `nc2` subarrays

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes the solutiion in the link is not `O(N*N)` , i am asking the maths behind this

Comment: (Is `noraml` similar to [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml)?) A great resource for integer sequences is the [Online Encyclopaedia](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,1,3,5,9,15,25&go=Search) dedicated to them - look at the first `FORMULA` for the first sequence it comes up with.

Comment: You can see the links getting useless (try the one from the 1st revision): please block-quote relevant information here (_with proper attribution & credit_) (_additional_ link welcome). Try using a spelling checker: `Arrray`, `i`, `noraml`, `Fibonaaci`. (No need to use `<br>`: follow the help and leave two trailing spaces at the end of a line you want a break after.) `Here is source code` for the problem in this question or the similar one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that runs in `O(N * log MAX_A * k^3)` time (where `MAX_A` is the maximum value in the array and `k` is the number of variables used in recursive formula (its equal to 2 for fibonacci and 3 for the problem your linked to your question). I will not refer to the source code you have provided as it's pretty hard to read but it looks like it uses similar ideas:

1. Let's learn how to compute the `i-th` Fibonacci number quickly. It's easy to see that `f(i) = F^n * [1, 1].transposed()`, where `F` is a matrix `[[1, 1], [1, 0]]` (it would be `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]` for the original problem. We can find the `n-th` power of a matrix quickly using binary exponentiation.
2. Let's develop this idea futher. In terms of matrices, we're asked to evaluate the following expression:

   ```
   sum for all valid L, R of ((F^(a[L] + ... + a[R]) * [1, 1].transposed())[0])
   ```

   or, equivalently (as matrix multiplication is distributive with respect to addition)

   ```
   ((sum for all valid L, R of F^(a[L] + ... + a[R])) * [1, 1].transposed())[0]
   ```
3. Now we need to figure out how to compute this sum efficiently. Let's learn to do it incrementally. Let's assume that all subarrays that end in a position `n` or smaller have already been processed and we want to add the next one. According to the problem statement, we should add `F^a[n + 1] + F^(a[n + 1] + a[n]) + ... + F^(a[n + 1] + a[n] + ... + a[0])` to the answer, which is equal to `F^a[n + 1] * (F^a[n] + F^(a[n] + a[n - 1]) + ... + F^(a[n] + a[n - 1] + ... + a[0]))`.
4. That's it. We already have an efficient solution. Here a pseudo code:

   ```
   pref_sum = I // identity matrix. This variable holds the second
   // term of the product used in step 3
   total_sum = zeros // zero matrix of an appropriate size
   // It holds the answer to the problem
   for i = 0 .. N - 1
       cur_matrix = binary_exponentiation(F, a[i]) // A matrix for the a[i]-th fibonacci number
       // Everything is updated according to the formulas shown above
       total_sum += pref_sum * cur_matrix 
       pref_sum = pref_sum * cur_matrix + I
   // Now we just need to mulitiply the total_sum by an appropriate vector
   // which is [1, 1].transposed() in case of Fibonacci numbers
   ```
5. Assuming that the size of the matrix `F` is constant (it's, again, 2 in case of Fibonacci numbers), the time complexity is `O(N * (log MAX_A + const)) = O(N * log MAX_A)` as there is just one binary exponentiation for each element of the original array followed by a constant number of matrix multiplications and additions.